# EmberJS - How to partially nest parent and sub routes?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a lot of nested urls.

e.g. `Project list` -> `Project detail`

The `Project list` template's route should only display the list if the route `Project details` is not called.

I did it by creating a computed property that check the `currentRouteName` of the server `routing`.

Then I add this to my template:

```
  <div>Element that should be display in both route.</div>

  {{#if isProjectDetail}}
    {{outlet}}
  {{else}}
    <ul> ... </ul>
  {{/if}}
```

Note that some elements of `Project list` should be still display in `Project detail`.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you use the wrong routes. use `projects/index` for the list and `projects/detail/:project_id` for the detail. Only put something in `projects` when it should be shown in both cases.

Comment: Ok that's exactly what I was looking for :)